# When is UserProfile initialized

Tags: asp.net, events, themes, httpmodule, profiles

I developed a HttpModule for assigning themes to pages during it's `PreInit` event from Profile of the logged in user. But seems the profile is not initialized at the time i access it. Is there a specific event after which i should access Profile for a user similar to access page cotnrols after `Init` event. btw i am running on ASP.NET 2.0 and Custom Profile Provider implementation.

```
 public void CurrentPageOnPreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the page currently requested
        Page currentPage = (Page)sender;

        //Get the user profile
        ProfileCommon userProfile = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;


            //check if user profile has theme set
            if (userProfile != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Theme))
            {
                //retrieve from profile
                currentPage.Theme = userProfile.Theme;
```

where the above method executes on `PreInit` stage of each page on my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to initialized in the OnPreInit method of the class.

override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e);

For methods execution follow this link it give brief about when which method will call asp.net life cycle.

Comment: since i have custom implementation do i have to do this Explicitly?? like `ProfileCommon.Create(UserName)` i hope not so since this is automatically carried out by asp.net framework somewhere during page parsing i am looking for exact event that this is carried out